# Hard time mapping the JSON in restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapping, restkit

I have a hard time mapping the JSON into my RestKit application. I want to save it also in core-data. Therefore here are two links to images.
First image, how my JSON looks like.

[IMAGE1](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8365852994/)

Second image is how my core-database looks like.

[IMAGE2](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8366272385/in/photostream)

Now first I made the application without the core-data layer. So just read the data and work with it. At that point everything worked. But with the core-data I got some mapping errors like this.

**LOG**

```
 2013-01-10 10:46:02.663 Offitel2[27978:6813] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:635 Did not find mappable relationship value keyPath 'Person'
2013-01-10 10:46:02.664 Offitel2[27978:6813] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:635 Did not find mappable relationship value keyPath 'Function'
2013-01-10 10:46:02.664 Offitel2[27978:6813] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:635 Did not find mappable relationship value keyPath 'Department'
2013-01-10 10:46:02.665 Offitel2[27978:6813] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:635 Did not find mappable relationship value keyPath 'Company'

2013-01-10 10:46:02.672 Offitel2[27978:164f] W restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:555 Caught undefined key exception for keyPath 'user' in mapping result: This likely indicates an ambiguous keyPath is used across response descriptor or dynamic mappings.
2013-01-10 10:46:02.673 Offitel2[27978:164f] W restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:555 Caught undefined key exception for keyPath 'function' in mapping result: This likely indicates an ambiguous keyPath is used across response descriptor or dynamic mappings.
2013-01-10 10:46:02.674 Offitel2[27978:164f] W restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:555 Caught undefined key exception for keyPath 'department' in mapping result: This likely indicates an ambiguous keyPath is used across response descriptor or dynamic mappings.
2013-01-10 10:46:02.676 Offitel2[27978:164f] W restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:555 Caught undefined key exception for keyPath 'company' in mapping result: This likely indicates an ambiguous keyPath is used across response descriptor or dynamic mappings.
```

This is how I do my relationship mapping in code.

```
 RKRelationshipMapping* relationUserMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Person"toKeyPath:@"user"withMapping:personMapping];
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationFunctionMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Function"toKeyPath:@"function"withMapping:functionMapping];
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationDepartmentMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Department"toKeyPath:@"department"withMapping:departmentMapping];
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationCompanyMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Company"toKeyPath:@"company"withMapping:companyMapping];
      NSLog(@"till here7");
    [dataMapping addPropertyMapping:relationUserMapping];
    [dataMapping addPropertyMapping:relationFunctionMapping];
    [dataMapping addPropertyMapping:relationDepartmentMapping];
    [dataMapping addPropertyMapping:relationCompanyMapping];
```

Can anybody please help me with this. I am struggling for days now on the mapping in core-data.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Try using RKManagedObjectMapping for this. Configure the RKManagedObjectMapping object as follows.

RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:serverUrl];

```
    RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

    objectManager.client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;

    objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:DB_NAME];

    objectManager.objectStore = objectStore;
```

Then you have to set the mapping for each of your data class and relationShip it has. I will just try to put one example here which i have used.

```
    /** specify the base mapping of reservation class */
    RKManagedObjectMapping *getReservationMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Reservation class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
    /** generate mapping for Reservation class */
    [self setReservationMapping:getReservationMapping];
    getReservationMapping.primaryKeyAttribute=@"reservationId";
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:getReservationMapping forKeyPath:@""];


    /** specify the base mapping of ReservationsType class */
    RKManagedObjectMapping *resTypeMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ReservationsType class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
    /** generate mapping for ReservationsType class */
    [self setReservationsTypeMapping:resTypeMapping];
    resTypeMapping.primaryKeyAttribute=@"reservationTypeId";
    [getReservationMapping mapRelationship:@"reservationsType" withMapping:resTypeMapping];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:resTypeMapping forKeyPath:@".reservationsType"];
```

where my setReservationMapping is as follows

```
    - (void)setReservationMapping:(RKManagedObjectMapping *)object
    {
     [object mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
       @"id", @"reservationId",
       @"comment", @"comment",
       @"date", @"date",
       @"email", @"email",nil];
    }
```

Here is my JSON sample. Note that my reservation node does not have identifier it is blank, hence i have given the keyPath:@"".

```
     [{
    id: 5644,
    comment: "",
    email: "danish@abc.com",
    firstName: "Danny",
    reservationsType:  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Reservation",
    }
    }]
```

Hope this helps you.